# Which timestamp format should I use?

Tags: timestamp, unix-timestamp, iso

What advantages does ISO 8601 have over the Unix time?

I often see it recommended nowadays.

Sample output:

```
.toISOString()  "2018-08-15T15:35:00.104Z"
.valueOf()      1534347300104
```

The latter seems advantageous in a number of ways:

1. Smaller payload (significant with thousands of timestamps in message/document)
2. No need to parse to do arithmetics, possible to store as initial timestamp + offsets
3. Easier to validate

The disadvantages I've heard already are:

- No leap seconds
- Rounded to millisecond

Are there any other dangers I should know about?